# Error while mapping a SharePoint Library - workaround

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-library, mapped-folder

You can easily run in error when it comes to mapping a SharePoint Library (especially in case you work in a highly restricted environment). 
Below you will see typical error messages you can receive in certain cases.

[image: Mapping via URL]

Or

[image: Mapping via Server]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways to sort it out.

**WORKAROUND 1: Mapping via URL**

Step 1: Go to the library and copy the link.

Step 2: Open it with "Open with Explorer" option (without this step you won't be able to map the library).

Step 3: Go to "Map Network Drive" and choose "Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your documents and pictures".

Step 4: Click "Next"

Step 5: Double click "Choose a custom network location".

Step 6: Paste the link and delete "/Forms/AllItems.aspx" part and click "Next".
[image: Mapping via URL - delete]

Step 7: Give it a name and click "Next". 
[image: Give it a name]

Step 8: Click "Finish" (at "Completing the Add Network Location Wizard"). 
[image: Mapping successful]

**WORKAROUND 2: Mapping via Server**

Step 1: Go to the library and copy the link.

Step 2: Open it with "Open with Explorer" option (without this step you won't be able to map the library).

Step 3: Go to "Map Network Drive"

Step 4: Transform the path to be Windows Explorer compatible. 
This means you have to replace the "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename" section with "\companyname365.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\sitename"

Step 5: Paste it in and click "Finish". 
[image: Correct Mapping - server]

Usually the system is not able to reconnect these network drives after restart, but if you go to any previously mapped library on SharePoint and choose "Open with Explorer", there is no need to do the mapping again, as it will help with reconnecting.